# Email notifications whenever a sheet is modified by code

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with a menu that has one item "Modify", which is bound to a function that modifies a cell in the active sheet:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(new Date().toString())
```

How to get an e-mail notification once this menu item is triggered.
I could get email notifications when the spreadsheet is modified manually.
I tried the onEdit function like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
   MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com", "Test Modify", "Hello!")
}
```

and also tried using a trigger that fires a function like this:

```
function alert(e){
   MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com", "Test Modify", "Hello!")
}
```

and I still receive no notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any triggers for this: just insert the email-sending command into the function that does the modification.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(new Date().toString())
MailApp.sendEmail("email@domain.com", "Test Modify", "Hello!")
```

---

By the way, simple triggers like `function onEdit()` [run in no-authorization mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#getting_started),  hence cannot send emails. Only installable triggers can send emails.

Comment: Thanks @404 . In fact, the script modifies several spreadsheets and sends emails to multiple addresses depending on which spreadsheets have been modified (they change every time). The solution you mentioned seems the most suitable one. I just want to make sure that the onEdit triggers are not activated whenever the spreadsheet is edited by code, **are they?** Or am I missing something?
It would be much easier if triggers could do the job.

P.S. Thanks for the link